# How to switch database connection at runtime in crystal reports using java swing

Tags: java, swing, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Please help. I am developing a swing application that can open reports made using crystal reports xi. What Im trying to do is to open a report and pass the connection info to that report so that I can dynamically change the database of the report. But for some reason it is not working and the report still produces the information from the database that it was initially set up. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?  Btw when I try using  com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument, I get a server not found error. But when I try to use import com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument; It's not working. I am not sure what a report server is and I dont think I set it up on my computer. Please help. Here is my code:

```
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument;

ReportClientDocument rpt =  new ReportClientDocument();
    rpt.open(reportPath+fileName, 0);
    Fields fields = null;

    IConnectionInfo connInfo = rpt.getDatabaseController().getConnectionInfos(null).getConnectionInfo(0);

     PropertyBag innerProp = connInfo.getAttributes();
        innerProp.clear();

        PropertyBag propertyBag = new PropertyBag();
        propertyBag.put("Server Type", "JDBC (JNDI)");
        propertyBag.put("Database DLL", "crdb_jdbc.dll");
        propertyBag.put("Database Class Name", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        propertyBag.put("Use JDBC", "true");
        propertyBag.put("Server Name", DBConnect.getServer());
        propertyBag.put("Generic JDBC Driver Behavior", "No");
        propertyBag.put("URI", "!com.mysql.jdbc.Driver!jdbc:mysql://"+DBConnect.getServer()+":"+DBConnect.getPort()+"/"+DBConnect.getDatabase()+"!ServerType=29!QuoteChar=`");

        connInfo.setAttributes(innerProp);
        connInfo.setPassword(DBConnect.getPassword());
        connInfo.setUserName(DBConnect.getUsername());




    int replaceParams = DBOptions._ignoreCurrentTableQualifiers + DBOptions._doNotVerifyDB;
    rpt.getDatabaseController().replaceConnection(rpt.getDatabaseController().getConnectionInfos(null).getConnectionInfo(0), connInfo, fields, replaceParams);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the properties added to propertyBag. You should either add the properties to innerProp, replacing propertyBag.put(...) with innerProp.put(...) or change connInfo.setAttributes(innerProp) to connInfo.setAttributes(propertyBag). I suggest the first approach.

Comment: Oops. my mistake. but actually if I use this code with the corrected propertyBag, I get a serverNotFound error. Any help on that?

Comment: Maybe you have a problem in DBConnect.

Comment: my DBConnect is working fine. I have other classes which depends on it. this is the exact error message:

    com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKServerException: There is no server specified.---- Error code:-2147217390 Error code name:serverNotFound. I always get that error whenever I use the import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument instead of com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument

Comment: btw we dont have crystal reports server installed in any of our computers. We only have crystal report designer which we thought is enough because on our C# and vb code, we were able to change database on a few lines of code.