# add a dynamic resultSet in Crystal Reports in eclipse

Tags: java, crystal-reports, report, datasource, resultset

My problem is this. I have Crystal Reports with Java in Eclipse, and I was unable to connect to a database using a JDBC connector IBM but graphically. But now I want to connect to the report by code, to pass data database, and can not find how to do it. Since Crystal Reports for Java does not allow me to use a ResultSet as a data source to generate the report dynamically.
Thanks

Comment: maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683249/how-to-switch-database-connection-at-runtime-in-crystal-reports-using-java-swing